# install 22.04.1 hangs at 'who are you?'

Tags: boot, system-installation

created the iso as per the docs and booted from usb. I have tried several options (minimum/normal/no updates etc) during the install process but always hangs at the who are you stage. The continue button is greyed out

the laptop had windows 10 installed previously but that is removed. I'm not sure what I need to do - is there something I need to check in the bios config?

Comment: Most probably reason is that the iso on the USB is damaged. That happens more often than you'd expect. You could try verifying the iso against the hash, to make sure that is the reason, or simply recreate the USB drive and try again.

Comment: I tried recreated the iso on another USB flash drive but still get the same problem where the continue button is greyed out after entering all the 'who are you' details

Answer (score 0):

on the Grub menu, choose ubuntu (safe graphics) instead of "try or install ubuntu" and follow the normal process afterwords. this worked for me.